# How to prove that the space of convergent sequences is complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X=\mathrm{Conv}(\mathbf R)$, the collection of all convergent sequences in $\mathbf{R}$. Is the normed space $(X,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ complete?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 6):

HINTS: Suppose that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$, where $x_n=\langle x_n(k):k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. You want to find a sequence $y=\langle y(k):k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in X$ such that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to y$.

1. Show that for each $k\in\Bbb N$, $\langle x_n(k):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$.
2. Use (1) to get a good candidate for $y$.
3. Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n-y\|=0\;.$$
4. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $p_n=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}x_n(k)$. Show that $\langle p_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to some $p\in\Bbb R$.
5. Show that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}y(k)=p$, and conclude that $y\in X$.